# Why pass parameters through thread function?

Tags: multithreading

When I create a new thread in a program... in it's thread handle function, why do I pass variables that I want that thread to use through the thread function prototype as parameters (as a void pointer)? Since threads share the same memory segments (except for stack) as the main program, shouldn't I be able to just use the variables directly instead of passing parameters from main program to new thread?

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes, you *could* use the variables directly. Maybe. Assuming that they aren't changed by some other thread before your thread starts running.

Also, a big part of passing parameters to functions (including thread functions) is to limit the amount of information the called function has to know about the outside world. If you pass the thread function everything it needs in order to do its work, then you can change the rest of the program with relative impunity and the thread will still continue to work. If, however, you force the thread to know that there is a global list of strings called `MyStringList`, then you can't change that global list without also affecting the thread.

Information hiding. Encapsulation. Separation of concerns. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass parameters to a thread function in any kind of normal register/stack manner because thread functions are not called by the creating thread - they are given execution directly by the underlying OS and the API's that do this copy a fixed number of parameters, (usually only one void pointer), to the new and different stack of the new thread.

As Jim says, failure to understand this mechanism often results in disaster.  There are numnerous questions on SO where the vars that devs. hope would be used by a new thread are RAII'd away before the new thread even starts.